# Get final position of element on a force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I been trying to solve this issue for weeks now, but I am not sure what is causing it.

I have a bouncing balls layout on which I am assigning a force layout in order to arrange the balls into groups. The issue I am having is that if I group and ungroup the balls fast (click on `group` then `run` again) then the ungrouping isn't smooth, as if the coordinates for each ball are wrong.

When I debug the code I see the `tick()` keeps running and assigning `x` and `y` values even when `balls` seem to be calm. I believe that might be the issue, and maybe the coordinates have a delay, but I don't know how to assign the final value of `tick()` before it ends.

My code was too big to paste here, but I created a Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6399zf7v/1/

After grouping and clicking `run`, `this.Move` is executed. If I do that quite fast then the error is there. If I wait a while before clicking run again the error seems to be smaller.

Any tip on the right direction will be appreciated in order to solve this issue. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure I see any problems with your code. Recall that the force layout is a [simulation that works on approximations](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#theta). The time between the ticks is always the same, but the math is different as the nodes get closer to each other - there is less room for adjustment.

Comment: it is tucking my page if my i am trying to `group-run` fast, maybe need to clear something?

Comment: @alexey sorry about that! I can't reproduce that but whatever is causing your page to crash might be the same that is causing the error with the coordinates. I went through the code many times and can't find it yet.